# Javascript remove a piece of a url

Tags: javascript, replace, str-replace

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <a href="http://domain.com/dev/topics/pagename" class="category">Test</a>
</div>
```

I have the above domain and which is I would like to remove the `topics/` part, I have tried the below piece of javascript but it always returns the url from the above example.

```
var breadcrumbURL = jQuery('.breadcrumbs .category').attr('href');
breadcrumbURL.replace("topics/", "");
console.log(breadcrumbURL);
jQuery('.breadcrumbs .category').attr('href',breadcrumbURL);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't change `breadcrumbURL`:

```
breadcrumbURL.replace("topics/", "");
```

it *returns* the string with the replaced text. To update the original, say:

```
breadcrumbURL = breadcrumbURL.replace("topics/", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not assigning the result of the `replace` to anything.

Change...

```
breadcrumbURL.replace("topics/", "");
```

To...

```
breadcrumbURL = breadcrumbURL.replace("topics/", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your line 2 by :

```
breadcrumbURL = breadcrumbURL.replace("topics/", "");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools. http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: I shiver ever time I see a reference to [w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com/) (See linked website for reasons)

Comment: Sorry if here it is not appreciated, but for JS i always found the necessary doc.

Comment: @BastienSander, read the website, and you'll see why the site is disliked on StackOverflow